# If contents of A3 match A2, I want it to turn green

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In Google Spreadsheets, if contents of A3 match A2, I want it to turn green. Contents in cell A2 will include numbers/text.

What formula should I use in conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

A `Custom formula is` of:

```
=A2=A3
```

for `Range:` A3 should suit whether for text, numbers, a mixture (string including alphabetic character/s and digit/s), or blanks.